# Cannot figure out REGEX java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a REGEX which can get string between two words. 
Here is the code,

```
Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("/\\x22(.*?)/\\x22");
Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher("sasaa \\x22 kjhkjhk \\x22,sasas");
while (m.find()) {
    String s = m.group(1);
    System.out.println("Tocken:"+s);
}
```

I am trying to get **kjhkjhk**  but matcher does not return anything, please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Remove the slashes.  Pattern.compile accepts only a pattern to match;  no delimiters or replacement text should be in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Pattern.compile("\\\\x22(.*?)\\\\x22");

You must escape backslash in Patterns with another backslash. Since backslash must be already escaped with another backslash in any Java string in the first place (like you did in the input string), you must have 4 of them in total.

Comment: It worked, pity me, for two \\ i have to add two \\ delimiters. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use this pattern:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\\\x22\\s(.*?)\\s\\\\x22");
    Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher("sasaa \\x22 kjhkjhk \\x22,sasas");
    while (m.find()) {
        String s = m.group(1);
        System.out.println("Tocken:"+s);
    }
}
```

Output:

> Tocken:kjhkjhk